# having trouble building multiple classes

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Ok, so I know this is a noob question but I am having trouble getting this code to work. What the code is supposed to do is give you the diamter when you input the radius. I know my code is probably butchered but what am I doing wrong and why because I am trying to learn.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle{

Scanner dd = new Scanner(ystem.in);

System.out.println("Whats is the radius?");
double r = dd.nextDouble();

public Circle(double r){

    radius = r;
}

public double diameter(){

    double d = radius * 2;
    return d;
}
}

public class Tester{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Circle cir1 = new Circle(35.5);
    System.out.println(Circle.diameter)
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Is there a compiler error message?  Does it crash?  Does it do the wrong thing?

Comment: Sorry only compiler error I get is that it does not contain a main type

Comment: This is an answer for a question you asked on Dec. the 15th that has been closed for some reason. [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put you code in a method. This block will cause an error :

```
Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Whats is the radius?");
double r = dd.nextDouble();
```

Next, in your main, you do Circle cirl = new Circle(35.5) and on the next line, you call Circle.diameter. You should call the diameter from you new instance as so cirl.diameter().

You could try something like this instead

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle{

    private double radius;

    public Circle(double r){

        radius = r;
    }

    public double diameter(){

        double d = radius * 2;
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Whats is the radius?");
        double r = dd.nextDouble();
        Circle cir1 = new Circle(r);
        System.out.println(cir1.diameter())
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run this code I get only 1 error. The variable cirl is unresolved in cirl.diameter()

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one `public` class in the same Java source file.  So either create two source files (one for each class), or define one class inside the other, e.g.:

```
public class Test {

    static class Circle {
       ...
    }

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly wrong, you can't have more than one public class in the same file.